# Unable to mark method with @objc, parameter cannot be represented in Objective-C

Tags: swift

I want to mark method @objc, to check in objc-runtime is this method is overridden.

```
class Animator<VC1: AnyObject, VC2: AnyObject>: NSObject  {
    @objc open func animation(vc1: VC1, vc2: VC2, container: UIView, duration: Double) {
        // .. 
    }
}
```

But get this error:

> Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter 1 cannot be represented in Objective-C

P.S. I saw previous questions on SO, but they didn't help me

**Edit:**

Maybe is possible to know before call is this method is overridden? User of this library can override this method. So inside lib I can do anything that I want.

```
if (!self.checkIsAnimOverridden()) {
  self.view.snapshot()
}
self.animation(vc1: vc1, vc2: vc2, container: container, duration: self.getDuration())
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift generics are not representable in Objective-C.**
This is why you get this error, although `AnyObject` is valid for Objective-C.

If you can, remove the generic:

```
class Animator: NSObject {
    @objc open func animation(vc1: AnyObject, vc2: AnyObject, container: UIView, duration: Double) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to use generics =( well, maybe there other option to get desired result. I need to know before call is this method overridden. Depends on it some custom code called before this method call.

Comment: Maybe you can solve this by having a non-generic base class for Objective-C.